# import-module failovercluster failing to load in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

I am using windows 2019 server, `import-module failovercluster` is giving an error

```
import-module : the specified module 'failovercluster' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

CategoryInfo: ResourceUnavailable: (failovercluster:string) [Import-Module], fileNotfoundException

FullyQualifiedErrorid: Modules_ModuleNotFound, Microsoft,Powershell,Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I have tried both powershell shells (x86) and non x86 shell.
Is there a way to import the failovercluster module?
I have also tried opening powershell (x64 )  from  following directory

> c:\windows\SysWow64\WindowsPowershell\v1.0

`Import-module failovercluster` gave similar module not found error.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Have you installed it? `Install-WindowsFeature Failover-Clustering`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
Install-WindowsFeature -name FailOver-Clustering -IncludeManagementTools
```

for Windows 2019 to get the correct modules.